# SQL insert trigger to catch NULL values for mutiple rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have written the trigger below that prevents from NULL being entered in the pch_x field . It works fine if i insert 1 row but doesnt work if I enter more than one at once . Could someone please help me out a little ? Here is my code

```
create trigger test 
ON [dbo].TEMP
for INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
declare @xcheck varchar(50)
set @xcheck= (select i.pch_x FROM temp L INNER JOIN INSERTED I
ON L.id = I.id)
F (@xcheck is NULL ) 
         begin 
         RAISERROR('NULL in pch_x', 16, 1) 
         ROLLBACK
         end 
END
```

Comment: Why isn't the column just declared as `NOT NULL`?

Comment: I know NOT null would be much simpler but my manager wanted it this way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing this in a trigger, but the set based way to do this test would be to use `EXISTS`:

```
create trigger test 
ON [dbo].TEMP
for INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
IF EXISTS(select * FROM temp L INNER JOIN
                        INSERTED I
                            ON L.id = I.id
          where i.pch_x IS NULL) 
         begin 
         RAISERROR('NULL in pch_x', 16, 1) 
         ROLLBACK
         end 
END
```

I'm also not sure why you're joining back to the table - I'd have thought the check could run without reference to `temp`:

```
create trigger test 
ON [dbo].TEMP
for INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
IF EXISTS(select * FROM INSERTED
          where pch_x IS NULL) 
         begin 
         RAISERROR('NULL in pch_x', 16, 1) 
         ROLLBACK
         end 
END
```

---

For you unusual requirement that, in a rowset containing some rows with nulls, you want success for those rows without nulls and failure for those rows with nulls, most sensible would be an `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
create trigger test 
ON [dbo].TEMP
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
declare @rc int
INSERT INTO dbo.temp (/* column list */)
SELECT /* column list */ from inserted where pch_x IS NOT NULL
set @rc = @@ROWCOUNT

IF @rc <> (select COUNT(*) from inserted)
         begin 
         RAISERROR('NULL in pch_x', 16, 1) 
         --ROLLBACK
         end 
END
```

Comment: HI , I have tried with EXISTS but when i insert the following rows none get inserted because there is a NULL in the 2nd row .Idealy i wanted the trigger to allow the not null(i.e. first row) to be inserted and ignore the 2nd row with null . INSERT INTO TEMP (ref,pch_x,id)
VALUES('Test TRIGGER', '666',31),
('',null,32)

Comment: removed join to Temp but getting the error that says _ "Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 9
NULL in pch_x
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."_ and NO rows entered in the table .

Comment: That's quite an unusual requirement - we normally want statements to *succeed* entirely or to *fail* entirely, and it's also unusual to report an error and yet still change the database.

Comment: Your last code does exactly what he asked for . Many thanks for this . I guess his point was that we would know exactly where the null is and sort that out at a later stage . To be honest I am not so clear as to why he wanted this .